# Label inside mdframed messes up spacing

Tags: spacing, mdframed, labels

I have a problem with `mdframed` in combination with `\parskip` and `\label`. Consider the following code, which is a MWE stripped down from a large document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\parskip=32pt

\begin{document}

  \begin{mdframed}[suppressfirstparskip=false,frametitle={Theorem 1.}]
  Text
  \label{Yeah}
  \end{mdframed}

  \begin{mdframed}[suppressfirstparskip=false,frametitle={Theorem 2.}]
  \label{Yeah}
  Text
  \end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

(I am aware of the fact that the `\label` command does not make sense here; it does in my original document and I see the same behaviour in that document). This code is rendered as follows:

[image]

Clearly, the second theorem has too much vertical space due to the `\label` command. Is there a way to fix this?

**EDIT**: After @Gonzalo Medina's answer, I added `\leavevmode` to the environment that I am actually using. This almost gets me to where I want to be, except there is still an unexpected space showing up in my document. The MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\parskip=32pt

\newenvironment{theorem}[1]%
  {\begin{mdframed}[suppressfirstparskip=false,frametitle={#1}]\leavevmode\ignorespaces}%
  {\end{mdframed}}     

\begin{document}

  \begin{theorem}{Theorem 1.}
  Text
  \label{Yeah}
  \end{theorem}

  \begin{theorem}{Theorem 2.}
  \label{Yeah}
  Text
  \end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

This is rendered as follows:

[image]

There is an extra space in the second environment.

**EDIT 2**:
I ended up replacing `\label` inside the `mdframed` scope:

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{theorem}[1]%
  {\begin{mdframed}[suppressfirstparskip=false,frametitle={#1}]%
   \let\@oldlabel=\label%
   \renewcommand\label[1]{\@oldlabel{##1}\ignorespaces}%
   \leavevmode\ignorespaces}%
  {\let\label=\@oldlabel%
   \end{mdframed}}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another instance of problems with material in vertical mode; use `\leavevmode`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\parskip=32pt

\begin{document}

  \begin{mdframed}[suppressfirstparskip=false,frametitle={Theorem 1.}]
  Text
  \label{Yeah}
  \end{mdframed}

  \begin{mdframed}[suppressfirstparskip=false,frametitle={Theorem 2.}]
  \leavevmode\label{Yeah}%
  Text
  \end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

[image]

After the edit to the question, I added a `%` character after the argument for `\label` in the second environment to prevent an undesired space.

If you are interested in theorem-like structures, perhaps you could use `\newmdtheoremenv`.

Comment: Hmm, I actually did add `\leavevmode\ignorespaces` to the beginning part of my environment; unfortunately now the space after `\label` is turned into an actual space... Is there a good way to deal with that as well?

Comment: @Yori you need to comment out the spacing: `\label{Yeah}%`

Comment: @Gonzalo_Medina: I was afraid so. Unfortunately I have a book full of theorems formatted like that. Is there no way around this? Interestingly, your code does not seem to suffer from the same problem. Why is that?

Comment: @Yori I don't see an easy way, other than commenting out the space or changing the placement of `\label`.

Comment: @Yori sure my code includes that space; I uploaded the wrong image that I produced with the commented-out sign; I accidentally deleted it in an edit.

Comment: @Yori -- i think that if you put the `\label` at the *end* of the theorem text, it would avoid the need for the `%` except in very extreme cases (when the last line of text can't accommodate one more space, and you get an extra, blank, line). this does make the presence of a label less obvious when you're reading the input, but there's unlikely to be more than one labelable element in such a frame.

Comment: @barbara: i am aware of that but I have about 50 theorems so I prefer to not have to edit each of them by hand. I think the solution I described above (with the overridden label command) works well.